# Understanding this programming challenge logic

Tags: math, language-agnostic, logic

I'm working through this [programming challenge](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=25&page=show_problem&problem=2290) and I'm having some difficulties understanding how the chess board is composed. From what I manage to understand is:

- We receive a board chess of size 4*4 which give us 16.
- We receive our input test for our attacker and we need to check with the formula abs(x-xi) + abs(y-yi) <= ri. The result of the operation needs to be less or equal to ri, if this conditional is correct that square of the chess board can be attacked by the attacker.

What I planned to do is starting a chess board where the first square is (0,0) and the last square is (3,3). I need to iterate from that first position, then do the operations to find if that square is less than Ri, if its less than mark that entrance with a counter and continue.

I did it by hand to check if the output of the first case was correct, I got a 5 reachable squares but the output got a 10. I redraw my chess board starting from (1,1) to (4,4) did the math by hand and also got a 5. The first test is (1,1,1) the attacker is in position (1,1) with a range of 1.

If I use the board starting in (0,0) the squares that can be attacked are: 2,5,6,7 and 10. If I use the board starting in (1,1) the squares are: 1,2,5,9 and 10.

Comment: First, I would stick with their notation and do things 1-based. Second, people do attack the square they are on. So in the first case, the (1,1) attacker attacks (1,1), (1,2), and (2,1), the (3,1) attacks (3,1), (3,2), and (4,1) [also (2,1), but we already counted that] and (3,3) attacks itself, (2,3), (3,4) and (4,3). [also (3,2), which we already counted] That is 10 squares attacked as claimed.

Comment: Also, I think you are going to have an easier time setting each square as not attacked, then iterating over the attackers and marking squares they do attack (at least that was easier for me in the hand calculation).

Comment: Let me know if in your mind the above constitutes an answer to your question, in which case I will post it as such. I am a little gun-shy on that front from some past comments and downvotes.

Comment: I'm understanding more how the problem is written but I also found another mistake from my logic with your explanation. The first case sends as a result 10, but we are taking the first three inputs (1,1),(3,1) and (3,3). The next case is (1,10) which I believe will be 0 because 10 is out of our board, but then we we receive another (1,1) which will get 3 [from your explanation], but the second case result is 2. English is not my first language sorry for the trouble. @JeremyKahan

Comment: The next case specifies a new board which is 1 by 10 with 1 attacker. That attacker sits on (1,1) and attacks (1,1) and (1,2) so 2 squares.

Comment: Now I get it, I wasn't paying attention to the number of attackers. @JeremyKahan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would stick with their notation and do things 1-based. Second, people do attack the square they are on. So in the first case, the (1,1) attacker attacks (1,1), (1,2), and (2,1), the (3,1) attacks (3,1), (3,2), and (4,1) [also (2,1), but we already counted that] and (3,3) attacks itself, (2,3), (3,4) and (4,3). [also (3,2), which we already counted] That is 10 squares attacked as claimed.
The next case specifies a new board which is 1 by 10 with 1 attacker. That attacker sits on (1,1) and attacks (1,1) and (1,2) so 2 squares. Then your algorithm should work (the way you describe, you would need to nest a second loop of iterations over attackers, but I would rather read an attacker at a time in a loop and then iterate over the squares).